# How can I copy(or move) and rename multiple files from different directories using the unix cp command?

Tags: linux, unix, shell, file-transfer, shell-script

Let's say, under this directory:
    `/home/data/`

There are 100 folders, the name of these folders are `24538_7#1`, `24538_7#2`, `24538_7#3` ... to `24538_7#384`.

In each folder, there are many files and folders.

The names of the desired file in each folder is Aligned.out.sam 
The desired folder for renamed files is `/home/SAM`

How can I copy all these files to the new folder(`/home/SAM`) and rename them properly as `24538_7#1.sam`, `24538_7#2.sam`, `24538_7#3.sam` ......?

I tried doing it by the command below but it didn't work:

`mv  /home/data/*/Aligned.out.sam /home/SAM/*.sam`

Comment: @bertieb I've included my effort in the question. Please have a look.

Comment: You mustn't use `*.sam` in the target. If there are no files in the target directory, a file called `*.sam` will be created there and each source file will overwrite it in turn. With an `mv` command this means that you will lose all your files apart from the last. If a `.sam` file exists in the target directory, each source file will overwrite it, as before. If multiple `.sam` files exist in the target directory, then all the source files **and** all the target files except the last will overwrite the last, so you will also lose existing `.sam` files in the target, apart from the second last.

Comment: The loop approach below is what you should use. The wildcard `*` won't work in the second invocation in that command, as bash has no idea you want each name on the left side to be the same as on the right side. Using a variable in a loop allows you to say "for each directory, copy the file and rename it to match the originating directory".

Comment: @AFH, I tried creating 384 sam files and then using the `mv` command too, but it didn't work.

Comment: @zymhan, can you help me with the proper way of doing it?

Comment: [Eugen Rieck](https://superuser.com/users/300968/eugen-rieck) has already given you an answer: @zymhan doesn't need to duplicate it.

Comment: @AFH, that answer isn't working. No file is either copied nor renamed

Comment: He needed to have either prefixed the directory in the `in` mask (`for sam in /home/data/*/Aligned.out.sam`) or emphasised that you need to be in `/home/data/` to run it, but it was intended as an outline, so you should be able to work that out.

Comment: There were some minor changes required. Now it's working fine. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something along the lines of

```
for sam in */Aligned.out.sam; do \
  name=$(basename $(dirname "$sam")) \
  cp "$sam" "/home/SAM/$name.sam" \
done
```

might do the trick

Comment: I would advocate the use of parameter parsing: `name=${sam%/*}; name=${name##*/}`. Your answer requires two nested subshells and two external programs.

Comment: @AFH Both `basename` and `dirname` are bash built-ins, not external programs. In addition to that bash hasn't been spawning a full subshell for this kind of construct for many versions. I also value the much better readability of the constructs much higher, then the few CPU cycles they might or might not cost. This is why I rejected your edit, but you are welcome to provide them in a second answer.

Comment: They are external programs on Ununtu `bash`, but I hadn't realised that `$()` doesn't invoke a subshell. Thanks for correcting me.